# Change of directories names according to pattern in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, find, one-liner

I need to change with one-liner (best option) directories name, more precise - to remove some prefix that has variable part at the beginning TO_BE_REMOVED_W._

I can find dirs to modification with:

```
find ./ -type d -iname 'TO_BE_REMOVED_W*' -exec mv {} _____ \;
```

How should I form execution part to rename directories to remove pattern from whole name?

Comment: If you don't have `rename` (as tdy suggested), but have zsh available, you could also use the internal command [`zmv`](https://www.lynda.com/Unix-tutorials/Renaming-files-zmv/2816007/2929324-4.html).

Answer (score 2):

Most distros come with `rename` which accepts substitution patterns, so I usually use `-execdir` with `rename`.

For example, to remove `PREFIX_`:

```sh
$ find . -execdir rename 's/^PREFIX_//' '{}' +
```

Note that for Arch Linux, this is called `perl-rename` ([Arch's default `rename` is not the standard `rename` found on most distros](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85128)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-exec bash -c '...'` like this:

```
$ find -name 'foo*'
./foo-01
./foo-05
./foo-02
./foo-03
./foo-04
$ find -name 'foo*' -exec bash -c 'file=$0; echo Now you can do anything with $file ...' {} \;
Now you can do anything with ./foo-01 ...
Now you can do anything with ./foo-05 ...
Now you can do anything with ./foo-02 ...
Now you can do anything with ./foo-03 ...
Now you can do anything with ./foo-04 ...
$
```